# Detectar o scroll do navegador nem sempre

Tags: jquery, rolamento, jquery-animate

Tenho um header animado, quando "scrolo" o site ele muda algumas coisas com animate, ou seja, quando o `$(this).scrollTop() > 0` (de 1 até 1 milhão, mas só quando sai da posição 0) ele anima e se volta para a posição 0 outra vez, ele anima para voltar ao layout inicial.

Ou seja, ele anima quando sai da posição 0 e anima outra vez caso volte para a posição 0 (só precisaria animar nesses dois momentos

**Código:**

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0){
        $('.topo_caixa').animate({backgroundColor: '#0033ff'}, 300);
        $('.topo_caixa').animate({height: 50}, 300);
        $('.topo_logo').animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
        $('.topo_botao').animate({marginTop: 10}, 300);
        $('.topo_botao a').animate({color: '#ffffff'}, 300);
        $('.topo_botao_linha').animate({backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}, 300);
    }else{
        $('.topo_caixa').clearQueue();
        $('.topo_logo').clearQueue();
        $('.topo_botao').clearQueue();
        $('.topo_botao a').clearQueue();
        $('.topo_botao_linha').clearQueue();
        $('.topo_caixa').animate({backgroundColor: '#f2f5ff'}, 300);
        $('.topo_caixa').animate({height: 100}, 300);
        $('.topo_logo').animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
        $('.topo_botao').animate({marginTop: 33}, 300);
        $('.topo_botao a').animate({color: '#0166ff'}, 300);
        $('.topo_botao_linha').animate({backgroundColor: '#0166ff'}, 300);
    }
});
```

A questão é, quando estou scrolando o site la embaixo, ele continua executando o animate, pois cai no `if($(this).scrollTop() > 0){...` e isso acaba consumindo processamento desnecessariamente, pois visualmente não influencia.

Queria que ele executasse a animação apenas quando realmente é necessário, só no momento que sair do **scrollTop 0** ou quando volta pro **scrollTop 0**

Comment: Só quer mesmo quando o scroll for 0, ou seja, a animação só ocorrer quando o scroll toda lá em cima?

Comment: Quando é 0 e quando não é. O problema é que na função que fiz, se to no scroll 100 e rolo até o scroll 200, ele fica executando o animate, mesmo sem precisar

Comment: use **(window).scrolltop()** ou veja o exemplo https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

Comment: Mas quer que anime quando o scroll for igual a quê? Desculpe não percebi

Comment: A sua condição creio que poderia ser qualquer coisa como `if($(window).scrollTop() < 10)` em vez de `if($(window).scrollTop() > 0)`

Comment: Oi, dei uma editada na explicação

Comment: @caiocafardo é não tente (this), não funciona, ele chama **document** este só papel, tem q usar **window** para global. `$(document).ready(function() { if((window).scrollTop() > 0){`

Comment: @KingRider não é isso não, acho q vc entendeu outra coisa...

Comment: ok caio, se quiser me passar o código completo te ajudo. envie skype live:sandro.alvares